# post to page with jQuery and read response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to post to a form using jQuery and read the results of the posted page.  I have created a super simple example.

```
    $('#submit').click(
        function () {
            $.get('post.htm',
                {
                    demo : "true"
                },
                function (data) {
                    alert('data load: ' + data);
                },)
        });
```

the html page for post.html is just a simple html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
this is a post
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what are you seeing? I would expect that clicking on the button with an id of 'submit' would alert the entire contents of `post.htm`.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: all i want to happen is for the contents of post.htm to alert.  thats it, its not doing that currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a subtle syntax error in your jQuery code: the line after your success callback should be `});` instead of `},)`.

If you fix that, this alerts the entire contents of `post.htm` when you click `#submit`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.get('post.htm',
            {demo : 'true'}, 
            function (data) { alert('data load: ' + data); 
        });
    });
});
```